# Trying to find location in GSM network

Tags: gsm, at-commands

I am using a GSM modem by Simcom [SIM 800E](http://www.reyax.com/Module/GSM/SIM800E/SIM800E_AT_Command_Manual_V1.00.pdf). I'm interfacing it over the serial link.

I am passing command `AT+CSCB` to get the location. But I am not getting it. I just get the response `OK`.

Can someone tell me the correct way to use this command?

The modem works fine while sending and receiving SMS.

Comment: I am not having any code as such, I am just giving these commands in terminal. ALso The modem works fine while sending and receiving SMS.

Comment: For reference: [here](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/07/0705/05.05.00_60/gsmts_0705v050500p.pdf) is the official GSM 07.05 documentation, which defines the `+CSCB` command.

Comment: Camil's answer is correct, try AT+CENG=2 and see what you get. That'll give you some cell information but I think it'll still be up to you to find the relation between a cell and its location. I believe places like Google do it by just driving around and recording, but maybe your local phone providers would be able to provide the data.

Comment: @PeterJ true, although Google uses wifi networks I believe. If the location doesn't have to be that accurate, a map of mobile networks would be sufficient.

Comment: Just had a look and the following might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82184/public-cell-id-databases

Answer (score 7):

AT+CSCB is to "Select Cell Broadcast SMS Messages" - not to get a location: (datasheet, p. 70)

[image]

What you can try is explained here. First send the Test Command, `AT+CSCB=?`. You should get a response with a list of supported modes. Then you can try the Read Command, `AT+CSCB?` and you should get the current mode  and so. At last you can try a Write Command, `AT+CSCB=<mode>` with `<mode>` one of the modes listed in the response to the Test Command. You can verify this change with the Read Command `AT+CSCB?`.

When you do want a location, try what PeterJ says in the comments on the question: send a `AT+CENG=2`. This sets the engineering mode (whatever that may be) and replies with all kinds of network information. Refer to the datasheet for an exact list, but it would include:

> < mcc > : mobile country code
>   < mnc > : mobile network code
>   < bsic > : base station identification code
>   < lac > : location area code

With the bsic, you can use [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20170317021206/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82184/public-cell-id-databases) to find your location. Other return variables may be useful as well.

Comment: What exactly is "Cell Broadcast SMS Messages" ?

Comment: @gpuguy it's a technique to send broadcast messages to multiple users in a network at once, see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast).

Comment: The post referred to by the link in the last sentence has been removed.

Comment: @rudolfbyker thanks, I have updated it with a link to the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 1):

open up any terminal window, And send the following AT commands. Here I am using Putty.

```
AT+CGATT =1 // to attach GPRS.

AT+SAPBR =3,1,”CONTYPE”,”GPRS” //activate bearer profile.

AT+SAPBR =3,1,”APN”,”RCMNET”

AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+SAPBR=2,1

AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1 //to get gsm location, time and date.

AT+CIPGSMLOC=2,1 //to get gsm time and date

AT+SAPBR =0,1 //to deactivate bearer profile.
```

If everything works fine, then your terminal will look as follows:
[Here is the screenshot of terminal](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/16/getting-location-from-gsm/)

So if everything goes well, you will get the longitude and latitude of your cell tower in degrees.

credits: [link](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/16/getting-location-from-gsm/)

Answer (score -1):

In SIM800 series you can use the commands AT+CIPGSMLOC or AT+CLBS. Both are location commands.